# Images in divs to be equals

Tags: html, css

How to make images in 3 divs to be equals.

```
.Row
{
   width: 130%;
   border-spacing: 20px;
   margin-left: 30px;
   padding:1em;

}
.Column
{
   display: table-cell;
}
```

Now they are differnet heigh. And here is html

```
<div class="Row">
 <div class="Column">
 ...
 </div>
 <div class="Column">
 ...
 </div>
 <div class="Column">
 ...
 </div>
</div>
```

You can see on the image what I talking about. If I try to put heigh in css nothing happen.

[Here is the link to image](http://s29.postimg.org/6znw2g3xz/bord.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want all the images to have the same height, you will have to specify the height of the images like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QvdL7/6/)**

**BUT**
you can make it much simpler with this HTML markup : **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QvdL7/8/)**

HTML :

```
<div class="Row">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-377-239-2.jpg" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-1209-1039-10.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.Row {
    border-top: 2px solid aqua;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    padding:20px 0;
}

.Row img {
    height:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.Column
{
   display: table-cell;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: if I add `float:left;` they got bigger... actual size.

Comment: yes, definitely then you have to fix its size as well

Comment: But I want to use existed images, not to make other size and thumbs?

Comment: image will not get bigger div size will change, image will remain same

Comment: even like this `float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px;` doesn't work

Comment: you can try to add `height: 100%;` and `width: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Its quiet simple.
Add below CSS to your main div,

```
display: inline-flex;
```

For your reference: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zLW9T/1/)

**Update:**
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zLW9T/2/)**

Comment: check the update,if my understanding is correct..I am working on chrome browser.

Comment: I need only one time 3 images and they to be with equal height.. not 3 x 3 images.

Comment: and look in the link what happen with `display:inline-flex;` I loose paddings... margins .. everything - http://s27.postimg.org/dlpvo1fgj/image.jpg

Comment: You have Provided only one image url.Looks like in the above comment ,You have got the solution.

Comment: Did you check the link here in the comments? You can clearly see that the 3 images are not the same height. The middle one is not like left and right one

Comment: can u please provide me the 3 images link?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/65hBU/ .. I need them on one height. So middle image to be like other two